# Почему возникает ошибка при импорте двух функций из модуля?

Tags: python

Это код рабочей программы:

```
def printing_models(unprinted_models, completed_models):
    """Имитирует печать моделей"""
    while unprinted_models:
        current_printing = unprinted_models.pop()
        print("Печатается в настоящий момент: " + current_printing)
        completed_models.append(current_printing)

def show_completed_models(completed_model):
    """Выводит информацию о напечатанных моделях"""
    print("\nНапечатанные проекты: ")
    for completed_model in completed_models:
        print(completed_model)

unprinted_models = ["iphone case", "robot pendant", "dodecahedron"]
completed_models = []

printing_models(unprinted_models, completed_models)
show_completed_models(completed_models)
```

Решил сохранить функции в отдельный модуль и потом попросту его импортировать. Однако после этого трассировщик почему-то выдает сообщение, что аргумент `completed_models` не определен

```
(NameError: name 'completed_models' is not defined)!
```

Ведь программа до этого выполнялась!

Почему выдает ошибку?

Файл, куда импортируется модуль:

```
#Файл, куда импортируется модуль
from printing_functions import *

unprinted_models = ["iphone case", "robot pendant", "dodecahedron"]
completed_models = []

printing_models(unprinted_models, completed_models)
show_completed_models(completed_models)
```

Импортируемый модуль

```
#Импортируемый модуль
def printing_models(unprinted_models, completed_models):
    """Имитирует печать моделей"""
    while unprinted_models:
        current_printing = unprinted_models.pop()
        print("Печатается в настоящий момент: " + current_printing)
        completed_models.append(current_printing)

def show_completed_models(completed_model):
    """Выводит информацию о напечатанных моделях"""
    print("\nНапечатанные проекты: ")
    for completed_model in completed_models:
        print(completed_model)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

**main.py**

```
#Файл, куда импортируется модуль
from printing_functions import *

unprinted_models = ["iphone case", "robot pendant", "dodecahedron"]
completed_models = []

completed_models = printing_models(unprinted_models, completed_models)   # + completed_models = ...
show_completed_models(completed_models)
```

---

**printing_functions.py**

```
#Импортируемый модуль
def printing_models(unprinted_models, completed_models):
    """Имитирует печать моделей"""
    while unprinted_models:
        current_printing = unprinted_models.pop()
        print("Печатается в настоящий момент: " + current_printing)
        completed_models.append(current_printing)
    return completed_models                                           # +++

def show_completed_models(completed_models):                          # - completed_model; + completed_models
    """Выводит информацию о напечатанных моделях"""
    print("\nНапечатанные проекты: ")
    for completed_model in completed_models:
        print(completed_model)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]